# How to make apex:pageBlockTable size to full screen size

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am building a visualforce page i have to make a visualforce page inside a pageblocksectionitem like i have shown in my code .i dont know much about css .my code is

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="item">
<apex:column value="{!item.name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

it is showing table width less than half to screen width .i dont know much about css but when i set style:{width:250%} then its width is increasing i have to set it how much percentage so its width will be equal to apex:pageblocktable without surrounded by apex:blockSection and apex:pageBlockSectionItem or any alternate please guideline

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add to pageBlockSection columns="1"

```
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
```